# Any idea how to add new contracts into drizzle react app using the address?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, addresses, react, drizzle

I have a react app which creates new contracts. lets say A creates B. 
I have the addresses of the newly created contracts of B.

How do i add the newly created contracts of B using its address to drizzle so i may use it.

Code examples would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you even want to go to drizzle, if you have the addresses in your react then why not use it from there or if you have it on your contract then fetch them to your react app